# How to use `preg_match()` to match a username

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate usernames in PHP using `preg_match()` but I can't seem to get it working the way I want it. I require `preg_match()` to:

1. accept only letters or numbers at the beginning and end of the string
2. accept periods, dashes, underscores, letters, numbers
3. must have a length between 5-20 characters

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/', $username)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break down the requirements into smaller pieces and you'll see that it becomes a lot easier:

- The first character must be 1 letter or number
- The middle characters must be a period, dash underscore, letter or number
- The last character must be a a letter or number
- As the first and last segments must be 1 character, the middle must be 3 to 18

```
~^[a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9._-]{3,18}[a-z0-9]{1}$~i
```

Comment: You don't need `{1}`, as the brackets imply matching any _one_ character in the set.  Also, you need to escape the dot in the second set of brackets otherwise it will match any character obviously.

Comment: @Madbreaks Actually, I think in that context, the period does not have to be escaped.  There would definitely be no harm in doing so though.  And as for the {1}, you're right that those are redundant, but I like to put them just out of partly habit and partly because I like my regular expresses as plain to the eye as possible.

Comment: Thanks Corbin, you're correct regarding the dot - thanks for pointing out MY mistake!

Comment: @user1307016 Hrmm, what is the string?  I just tested "a" 21 times, and it came back false.  As far as I can tell rereading the pattern, it's impossible for anything over 20 characters to be matched (as desired).  Have you altered the regex, and if so, to what?

Comment: Oops. Never mind. It works like a charm. Forgot the $ to denote the end of the string. Silly me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If the regex is confusing you, you could always match the characters with a regex and then explicitly check for the length of the string with `strlen()`.

```
$valid = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\d]+[\w.-]*[a-zA-Z\d]$/', $username)
         AND strlen($username) >= 5 AND strlen($username) <= 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match('~^[0-9a-z][-_.0-9a-z]{3,18}[0-9a-z]$~i', $username) > 0)
{
    // valid
}
```

Comment: You need to escape that dot in the second set of brackets or it will match any character of course.